# How to force a connection to a certain host to use to a specific source IP?

Tags: linux, ip

When using the Shoutcast2 yellowpages there is a really annoying issue that it always uses the default IP the system uses for an outgoing conection to register itself even if the server is configured to listen on a different ip - I guess I don't need to mention that this makes no sense and the YP system unusable. Marking all other IPs of the systems as deprecated is not an option; I don't want the stream IP to be the default IP for other outgoing connections.

So what I'm looking for is a way to make those connections (always to yp.shoutcast.com:80) use a certain source IP address. An existing tool would be perfect but a solution that requires not-too-much coding would be fine, too. I also have root access on the machine so iptables-based solutions would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iptables can do this easily with the SNAT target:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT \
    -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 --destination yp.shoutcast.com \
    --to-source $STREAM_IP
```

Comment: On a side-note: If anyone plans to use this for the same reason I do: Don't match by `--destination`, use the owner/uid match instead. The YP host is round-robin-ish and thus you'd need to create rule for all those ips.

Comment: Using the name will match all IPs returned by DNS. And usually something binding to "the wrong IP" because the routing table is improperly configured. If I could see it I could probably tell you what's wrong.

Comment: The DNS returns only one ip; they round-robined the NS records.

Answer (score 1):

```
ip route add 205.188.87.240 dev eth0 src $SRC_ADDR
```